# HSQLDB and Array

Tags: arrays, hsqldb

Hsqldb 2.0 documentation talk about array and report this example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INT PRIMARY KEY, scores INT ARRAY DEFAULT ARRAY[], names VARCHAR(20)
ARRAY[10])
```

I tried it but I obtain this exception:

```
[Error Code: -5581, SQL State: 42581]  unexpected token: ARRAY
```

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently using a pre-release version. Download the latest 2.0.1 snapshot jar from the http://hsqldb.org/support/ page. (BTW, the GA release version 2.0.0 also supports arrays and your CREATE TABLE statement, the snapshot has more recent bugfixes)